# Reshape a stacked style data file into a dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, reshape

I have a csv input file with the below format and i'm looking for a fairly easy way to convert to normal shape dataframe in pandas. the csv data file has all data stacked up into two columns with each data block separated by an **empty row** like below.
note for the ease of explanation, i made the **timestamp values the same** for the three blockset, but in reality **they can be different**:

```
Trace Name,SignalName1
Signal,<signal info>
Timestamp,Value
2023-10-04 15:36:43.757193 EDT,13
2023-10-04 15:36:43.829083 EDT,14
2023-10-04 15:36:43.895651 EDT,17
2023-10-04 15:36:43.931145 EDT,11
,
Trace Name,SignalName2
Signal,<signal info>
Timestamp,Value
2023-10-04 15:36:43.757193 EDT,131
2023-10-04 15:36:43.829083 EDT,238
2023-10-04 15:36:43.895651 EDT,413
2023-10-04 15:36:43.931145 EDT,689
,
Trace Name,SignalName3
Signal,<signal info>
Timestamp,Value
2023-10-04 15:36:43.757193 EDT,9867
2023-10-04 15:36:43.829083 EDT,1257
2023-10-04 15:36:43.895651 EDT,5736
2023-10-04 15:36:43.931145 EDT,4935
```

the desired output after reshaping should look like the following:

```
    Timestamp           SignalName1 SignalName2 SignalName3
0   10/4/2023 15:36:43  13          131         9867
1   10/4/2023 15:36:43  14          238         1257
2   10/4/2023 15:36:43  17          413         5736
3   10/4/2023 15:36:43  11          689         4935
```

Comment: "but in reality they can be different": then what's supposed to happen? Fill with `NaN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the file using the multi newlines, then [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) on each chunk and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
import re
import io

with open('csv_file.csv') as f:
    out = (pd.concat([pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(chunk),
                                  header=0, skiprows=[1,2])
                        .set_index('Trace Name')
                      for chunk in re.split('(?:\n,)+\n', f.read())
                      if chunk], axis=1)
             .rename_axis('Timestamp').reset_index()
          )
```

Assumptions (can be tweaked if needed):

- there are 3 rows in each header
- the first row of each header is "Trace Name" then the name to be used as column

Output:

```
             Timestamp  SignalName1  SignalName2  SignalName3
0  2023-10-04 15:36:43           13          131         9867
1  2023-10-04 15:36:43           14          238         1257
2  2023-10-04 15:36:43           17          413         5736
3  2023-10-04 15:36:43           11          689         4935
```

Comment: thank you for help! when executing your code on my data file, i'm getting the following errors:
    raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
KeyError: "None of ['Trace Name'] are in the columns"

Comment: @Hannibal as explained in my answer, I made the assumption that "Trace Name" is in the first row header of each block. Is this not the case in your real dataset? Can you first try on the example that you provided?

Comment: your 1st & 2nd assumptions are valid.  it is the case in my real dataset file. yes, i did try this on the real data file and on this example datafile. bothh output same error.

Comment: @Hannibal then you have to be more explicit and provide a fully reproducible example to reproduce this error. With your current example this works well in my hands… Also check the intermediates to see what happens exactly. For instance, if you comment the `set_index` and `rename_axis` lines of code, what is the output of `list(out)`?

Comment: is there a way to place the csv file i'm getting the error for here?
this is the ouput of list(out) after commenting out the set_index: note i couldnt paste the  whole thing, but the other chunkcs are listed below this one in same way

 Timestamp                        Trace Name,SignalName1
0           0             2023-10-04 15:36:43.757193 EDT,13
1           1             2023-10-04 15:36:43.829083 EDT,14
2           2             2023-10-04 15:36:43.895651 EDT,17
3           3             2023-10-04 15:36:43.931145 EDT,11
4           4                                             ,

Comment: i updated data format in description on top. hopefully this makes it more explicit.

Comment: @Hannibal I see, then the separator and regex need to be updated. See above.

Comment: how the obove can be updated to accommodate data files that includes the 3 rows headers (
Trace Name,SignalName1
Signal,<signal info>
Timestamp,Value
 ) but missing data? that is to ignore SignalNames that do not have data associated with them?

Comment: @Hannibal better open a new question will all the details

Comment: done! look for "Reshape stacked form data in csv file using pandas" question

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I find it useful to intercept a text stream (e.g. from a `TextIOWrapper` open file) and modify it in a streaming fashion.

That method works with arbitrarily large files. Example applications include:

- correcting known errors;
- skipping (filtering out) parts of a file;
- injecting extra data.

You could do that here and inject a "key" in each line. The key is obtained when the processor encounters `Trace Name,key`.

With the appropriate custom `Proc` and a utility class `FileModifier` (defined below), the usage is simply:

```py
with open('test.csv') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(FileModifier(f, Proc().proc))
```

Then, a custom processor for your case would be:

```py
class Proc:
    def __init__(self):
        self.key = None
    
    def proc(self, line):
        if (m := re.match(r'^Trace\s+Name,(.*)', line)):
            send_header = self.key == None 
            self.key = m.group(1)
            if send_header:
                return 'SignalName,Timestamp,Value\n'
        elif re.match(r'^\d{4}', line):
            return f'{self.key},{line}'
```

Finally, the `FileModifier` class (that you can use for many different kinds of on-the-fly modifications) is:

```py
class FileModifier:
    def __init__(self, f, proc):
        self.f = f
        self.buffer = io.StringIO()
        self.proc = proc
        self.linestream = iter(self._lines())

    def _lines(self):
        for line in self.f:
            out = self.proc(line)
            if out is not None:
                yield out
        
    def read(self, size=-1):
        try:
            while size < 0 or self.buffer.tell() < size:
                self.buffer.write(next(self.linestream))
        except StopIteration:
            pass
        if size >= 0 and self.buffer.tell() > size:
            newbuf = io.StringIO()
            self.buffer.seek(0)
            out = self.buffer.read(size)
            newbuf.write(self.buffer.read())
            self.buffer = newbuf
        else:
            out = self.buffer.getvalue()
            self.buffer.seek(0)
            self.buffer.truncate()
        return out
```

#### Example

With a file `test.csv` containing your example data:

```py
with open('test.csv') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(FileModifier(f, Proc().proc))
>>> df
     SignalName                       Timestamp  Value
0   SignalName1  2023-10-04 15:36:43.757193 EDT     13
1   SignalName1  2023-10-04 15:36:43.829083 EDT     14
2   SignalName1  2023-10-04 15:36:43.895651 EDT     17
3   SignalName1  2023-10-04 15:36:43.931145 EDT     11
4   SignalName2  2023-10-04 15:36:43.757193 EDT    131
5   SignalName2  2023-10-04 15:36:43.829083 EDT    238
6   SignalName2  2023-10-04 15:36:43.895651 EDT    413
7   SignalName2  2023-10-04 15:36:43.931145 EDT    689
8   SignalName3  2023-10-04 15:36:43.757193 EDT   9867
9   SignalName3  2023-10-04 15:36:43.829083 EDT   1257
10  SignalName3  2023-10-04 15:36:43.895651 EDT   5736
11  SignalName3  2023-10-04 15:36:43.931145 EDT   4935
```

Which of course you can reshape:

```py
>>> df.pivot(index='Timestamp', columns='SignalName', values='Value')
SignalName                      SignalName1  SignalName2  SignalName3
Timestamp                                                            
2023-10-04 15:36:43.757193 EDT           13          131         9867
2023-10-04 15:36:43.829083 EDT           14          238         1257
2023-10-04 15:36:43.895651 EDT           17          413         5736
2023-10-04 15:36:43.931145 EDT           11          689         4935
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the file consists in two comma-separated columns thoughout, another possibility is to read it using minimal `csv_read` parameters, followed by post-processing.

#### 1. Minimal read_csv

```
raw = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', 
                  sep=',', 
                  header=None,                  # Prevents first file line from being mistaken for column names
                  names=['Timestamp','Value'])  # Select columns names yourself instead
raw

                         Timestamp          Value
0                       Trace Name    SignalName1
1                           Signal  <signal info>
2                        Timestamp          Value
3   2023-10-04 15:36:43.757193 EDT             13
4   2023-10-04 15:36:43.829083 EDT             14
5   2023-10-04 15:36:43.895651 EDT             17
6   2023-10-04 15:36:43.931145 EDT             11
7                              NaN            NaN
8                       Trace Name    SignalName2
9                           Signal  <signal info>
10                       Timestamp          Value
11  2023-10-04 15:36:43.757193 EDT            131
12  2023-10-04 15:36:43.829083 EDT            238
13  2023-10-04 15:36:43.895651 EDT            413
14  2023-10-04 15:36:43.931145 EDT            689
15                             NaN            NaN
16                      Trace Name    SignalName3
17                          Signal  <signal info>
18                       Timestamp          Value
19  2023-10-04 15:36:43.757193 EDT           9867
20  2023-10-04 15:36:43.829083 EDT           1257
21  2023-10-04 15:36:43.895651 EDT           5736
22  2023-10-04 15:36:43.931145 EDT           4935
```

---

At this stage `raw.dtypes` is all `object` because the rows are not homogeneous but a quick sorting is possible.

```
Timestamp    object
Value        object
dtype: object
```

---

#### 2. Post-processing

```
# Move signal name to a new column
df['SignalName'] = np.where(df['Timestamp']=='Trace Name', df['Value'], np.nan)
df['SignalName'].ffill(inplace=True)

# Drop all non numerical rows
df = df[df['Value'].str.match(r'^([\d\.]+)$', na=False).values] # regex matches only numbers, either integers or decimal
df

                         Timestamp Value   SignalName
3   2023-10-04 15:36:43.757193 EDT    13  SignalName1
4   2023-10-04 15:36:43.829083 EDT    14  SignalName1
5   2023-10-04 15:36:43.895651 EDT    17  SignalName1
6   2023-10-04 15:36:43.931145 EDT    11  SignalName1
11  2023-10-04 15:36:43.757193 EDT   131  SignalName2
12  2023-10-04 15:36:43.829083 EDT   238  SignalName2
13  2023-10-04 15:36:43.895651 EDT   413  SignalName2
14  2023-10-04 15:36:43.931145 EDT   689  SignalName2
19  2023-10-04 15:36:43.757193 EDT  9867  SignalName3
20  2023-10-04 15:36:43.829083 EDT  1257  SignalName3
21  2023-10-04 15:36:43.895651 EDT  5736  SignalName3
22  2023-10-04 15:36:43.931145 EDT  4935  SignalName3
```

The data has been retrieved, now reshape it as you requested:

```
# Regroup by signal name
pd.pivot_table(data    = df,
               values  = 'Value',
               columns = 'SignalName',
               index   = 'Timestamp')

SignalName                     SignalName1 SignalName2 SignalName3
Timestamp                                                         
2023-10-04 15:36:43.757193 EDT        13.0       131.0      9867.0
2023-10-04 15:36:43.829083 EDT        14.0       238.0      1257.0
2023-10-04 15:36:43.895651 EDT        17.0       413.0      5736.0
2023-10-04 15:36:43.931145 EDT        11.0       689.0      4935.0
```